# Change friends display name (Alias) using XMPP

Tags: ios, xmpp, alias

I need to change the display name or Alias of friends using XMPP.Please help.

Comment: How do you expect us to help you?

Comment: Let me know if there's any way to change friend's alias name using only XMPP.I don't have any web service for that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Section 2.4.1 of RFC 6121](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6121.html#roster-update-request) has an example of how to do that.  Given that `romeo@example.net` has the display name "Romeo", the following stanza changes the name to "MyRomeo":

```xml
C: <iq from='juliet@example.com/balcony'
       id='gb3sv487'
       type='set'>
     <query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'>
       <item jid='romeo@example.net'
             name='MyRomeo'/>
     </query>
   </iq>
```